# How to log Test Suite name before suite

Tags: java, selenium, log4j, testng

I want to log name of the test suite before running it. I succeed on logging method names but couldn't figure out how I can do the same thing with suites. My code:

EDIT: I found the solution. Here is the code for those who need it.

```
public class TestCase {

private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
protected static WebDriver driver;

private String url = PropertyManager.getUrl();
private String browser = PropertyManager.getBrowser();

@BeforeSuite
protected void setUp(ITestContext tes) { 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "chromedriver.log");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    logger.info("Starting up {} driver.", browser);


    logger.info(tes.getSuite().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding Listener in the project. Use `IInvokedMethodListener` to perform activities before invocation of intended method.

**Steps**:

1. Create a class lets say `ListenerClass` and implement `IInvokedMethodListener` interface in it.

   ```
   public class ListenerClass implements IInvokedMethodListener
   ```
2. Add all unimplemented method and add below code in `beforeInvocation` method :

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @Override
   public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

       try {
           if (method.getTestMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite.class)
               .toString() != null) {
               System.out.println("Before suite annoted method name - " + method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
               System.out.println("Test suite name  - " + testResult.getTestContext().getSuite().getName());
            }
       } catch (Exception e) {
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add the listener class in your `testng.xml` file

   ```
   <listeners>
       <listener class-name="ListenerClass"></listener>
   </listeners>

   <test name="Test_Name">
       <classes>
           <class name="Test_Class_Name" />
       </classes>
   </test> <!-- Test -->
   ```

Run `testng.xml` as TestNGSuite you will get the expected result. Let me know if any thing is there

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting error = Document root element "listeners", must match DOCTYPE root "suite". I updated the question accordingly and added testng.xml as well.

Comment: `<listeners>
    <listener class-name="ListenerClass"></listener>
</listeners>` add this

Comment: I added but I get the above error. Where should I add it exactly?

Comment: Inside suite tag in XML and don't forget to add the listener class with package name